# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Openstreetmap problem

Tags: header, leaflet, marker

Hi I'm trying to use `http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/searchformat=json&q=` on a WordPress site to get long and lat from an adresse to set markers on a leaflet map and it works fine as long a I'm logged in as an admin but when I'm not I get this error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q=3%20rue%20du%20G%C3%A9n%C3%A9ral%20Leclerc,%20Schwindratzheim' from origin 'http://isad-confort.projet-maquette.fr' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I can't find an answers that I understand on how to set the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, can someone explain me what I should do.

Comment: Try `https` rather than `http`.

Comment: Won't work I get error 404

Comment: That doesn't seem likely.

Comment: Can you explain qhere i should change http into https ? In my domain name or on the openstreetmap link ?

Comment: `http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org` should be `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org`

Comment: I call it like this ```jQuery.get(location.protocol + '//nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q=' + '<?php the_field('adresse'); ?>', function(data) {...});``` and if I try to put `https:` before like this ```jQuery.get(location.protocol + 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q=' + '<?php the_field('adresse'); ?>', function(data) {...});``` I get this error ```GET http://isad-confort.projet-maquette.fr/realisations/https:/nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q=31%20Rue%20Principale%2067270%20Ingenheim 404 (Not Found)```

Comment: `jQuery.get('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/...`

Comment: It worked thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

I solved it juste needed to change my request from 
`jQuery.get(location.protocol + '//nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q='`

To
`jQuery.get('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q='`

Thanks peeebeee